# How to programatically Activate (being Selected) a Document from AvalonDockManager?

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock

I've created a `DockingManager` from `AvalonDock` content in my project and my request is quite simple: when I add a document to my LayoutDocumentPaneGroup I want it to be Active, Selected, and not only add at the end of the LayoutDocumentPaneGroup still activate on the first document.

I tried to implement an `IsActive` property to my documentView class but it doesn't work.

My dockingmanager in xaml file is defined as below:

```
<dock:DockingManager DataContext="{Binding DockManagerViewModel}" DocumentsSource="{Binding Documents}"  AnchorablesSource="{Binding Anchorables}">
    <dock:DockingManager.Resources>
    <!-- add views for specific ViewModels -->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vmdock:SampleDockWindowViewModel}">
            <uscontrol:SampleDockWindowView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </dock:DockingManager.Resources>
    <dock:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type dockctrl:LayoutItem}">
                                <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.Title}" />
                                <Setter Property="CloseCommand" Value="{Binding Model.CloseCommand}" />
                                <Setter Property="CanClose" Value="{Binding Model.CanClose}" />
                            </Style>
                        </dock:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
                        <dock:LayoutRoot>
                            <dock:LayoutPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <dock:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
                                    <dock:LayoutDocumentPane />
                                </dock:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
                                <dock:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup>
                                    <dock:LayoutAnchorablePane />
                                </dock:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup>
                            </dock:LayoutPanel>
                        </dock:LayoutRoot>
                    </dock:DockingManager>
```

My documentView is defined with the class as below:

```
public abstract class DockWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    #region Properties

    #region CloseCommand
    private ICommand _CloseCommand;
    public ICommand CloseCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_CloseCommand == null)
                _CloseCommand = new RelayCommand(call => Close());
            return _CloseCommand;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region IsClosed
    private bool _IsClosed;
    public bool IsClosed
    {
        get { return _IsClosed; }
        set
        {
            if (_IsClosed != value)
            {
                _IsClosed = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsClosed));
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region CanClose
    private bool _CanClose;
    public bool CanClose
    {
        get { return _CanClose; }
        set
        {
            if (_CanClose != value)
            {
                _CanClose = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CanClose));
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Title
    private string _Title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _Title; }
        set
        {
            if (_Title != value)
            {
                _Title = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Title));
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #endregion

    public DockWindowViewModel()
    {
        CanClose = true;
        IsClosed = false;
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        IsClosed = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found ! I post the result because I think I'll not be alone...
First, I add a new property to my document view definition:

```
#region IsSelected
        private bool _isSelected = false;
        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get
            {
                return _isSelected;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_isSelected != value)
                {
                    _isSelected = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsSelected));
                }
            }
        }
#endregion
```

But I had also to implement it as a property in my XAML code, as below:

```
<dock:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type dockctrl:LayoutItem}">
        <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.Title}" />
        <Setter Property="CloseCommand" Value="{Binding Model.CloseCommand}" />
        <Setter Property="CanClose" Value="{Binding Model.CanClose}" />
        **<Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Model.IsSelected}" />**
    </Style>
</dock:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
```

Supposed it works the same for all properties of LayoutContent defined there: [LayoutDocument defined by AvalonDock](https://xceed.com/wp-content/documentation/xceed-toolkit-plus-for-wpf/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock~Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Layout.LayoutDocument_members.html)

**EDIT :**
Need to add also "Mode=TwoWay" to programmatically update when the selected content changed, like this:

```
<Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Model.IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: Not sure how you made this work. I had no success using this solution and I can't get rid of a `StackOverflowException` when using `Mode=TwoWay`.

Answer (score 0):

As I already mentioned in my comment on the accepted answer, this didn't work for me, so I moved on trying. My case may differ, though. I'm using Stylet and my `DockManager.DocumentsSource` is bound to the `Items` property of a `Conductor<MyViewModelBase>.Collection.OneActive Documents` in the ViewModel. In this case I needed to do two things to activate the added document:

1. Bind `DockingManager.ActiveContent` to `Documents.ActiveItem`
2. After `Documents.Items.Add(an_instance_of_my_viewmodel);` activate the new ViewModel with `Documents.ActivateItem(vm);`